# How can I set different Text for each row in DataGridViewLinkColumn?

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView which binds data from Database. And I add DataGridViewLinkColumn to DataGridView so I can click some links for edit or delete for each data. But some data do not need to be edited or deleted. I want to disable or set empty of some cells in DataGridViewLinkColumn. I tried many ways but I cannot set different text each cell. I can only set all cells with the same text. Is there any simple way to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a RowDataBound event for the grid.  In that event you can can do the conditional formatting you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: I'm working at c# forms application. I cannot find this event.

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't exist for Forms.  If you only want different text for different rows, you can do some conditional formatting in your database query.

Comment: Finally, I solve it by creating my own control. Anyway, Thanks for your ideas.